# Graph Theory Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

The given problem is

Given a forest with n vertices, add edges to make it into a tree with
minimal diameter.
I tried many approaches but none of them passed system test cases.Please suggest some algorithm to solve this problem.

This is the link of the editorial [ncpc.idi.ntnu.no/ncpc2015/ncpc2015slides.pdf](http://ncpc.idi.ntnu.no/ncpc2015/ncpc2015slides.pdf) The problem name is Adjoin the Networks. I am not able to understand the solution provided in the editorial

Update:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-solution-for-Dreaming-on-IOI-2013

This link provides the best explanation for the solution mentioned in the editorial

Answer (score 1):

The eccentricity of a vertex `v`, denoted `ecc(v)`, is defined as `ecc(v):=max_u d(u,v)`, i.e. as the distance to a most distant vertex in the graph. A *center* of a graph`G` is any vertex `v` for which `ecc(v)=min_v max_u d(u,v)`, i.e. a center is a vertex that minimizes the eccentricity.

If you merge two trees (from different connected components), `T1` and `T2`, by putting an edge between their centers `c1` and `c2`, you get a tree `T` with `diam T = max(diam T1, diam T2, 1+rad(T1)+rad(T2))`.

The correctness of the approach below should be evident from these properties.

Here's one idea for the algorithm, off the top of my head:

- let `T1`, `T2`, ..., `Tk` be the trees comprising the forest.
- compute a [center vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_%28graph_theory%29) `ci` for each of the trees `Ti`.
- connect components by putting edges between centers in an intelligent way.

Of course, the problem is now how to cleverly solve the  last bullet. Intuitively I'd suggest you connect the treest with the largest diameters first (and then update the diameter of the new tree and compute a center of the new tree). Perhaps something like this:

**while** the priority queue contains more than one tree **do**

- let `T1` and `T2` be the trees with the largest diameters; let `c1` and `c2` be their centers;
- connect `c1` and `c2` to form a new tree `T`;
- compute a new center `c` of `T`, compute `diam T` and put `T` back into priority queue (which can be a max-heap that uses diameter as the key).

**done**

**Update.** I'm not sure whether to join largest-diameter trees first or the other way around (i.e. smallest-diameter trees first). But it's now very easy to do a sketch of a proof (once you figure out which way to go) that this is the right way to go.

**Update.** The math certainly goes through if you connect largest first (as suggested in the PDF).

Comment: Actually tried this approach but it gave Time limit exceeded

Comment: Solution as per the editorial is  is the maximum of:
Largest diameter of a tree,
The sum of the largest and second largest radii +1,
The sum of the second and third largest radii +2  .The problem is  I dont understand how this solution can be correct

Comment: I don't understand the last comment. Regarding the first comment, you might have used an inefficient implementation of some of the steps.

Comment: this is the link of the editorial https://ncpc.idi.ntnu.no/ncpc2015/ncpc2015slides.pdf The problem name is  Adjoin the Networks

Comment: Thanks for sharing the PDF. I'm surprised about the statement "Every tree connects to the one of largest diameter." It seems my intuition was a bit off regarding the last bullet. I'll think more about it.

Comment: Regarding the time limit exceeded, I'm now absolutely sure this is the way to go. It all depends on how you are computing the intermediate steps (centers and diameters, and whether you're using heap for the while loop).

Comment: I will recheck my code but can you please explain the solution mentioned in the PDF . thanks in advance

Comment: Hm, the first two bullets are clear: they are what I wrote at the beginning of the asnwer. I'm a bit puzzled by the last bullet (sum of the second largest and third largest radii + 2). I'll think about it.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-solution-for-Dreaming-on-IOI-2013 this link provides the best explanation @blazs